# Automatic import error of .vue module in Volar of VSCode

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs3, volar

```
[TS Error] Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Some exportInfo should match the specified moduleSymbol {}
```

The above error occurs.

The message looks like a TypeScript related error, but my project uses Javascript only

I tried to refer to 'https://github.com/vuejs/language-tools/issues/2190' this issue, but it didn't help because I didn't use TypeScript

Comment: VSC relies on TS, so the issue is still relevant. It's unlikely that somebody's able to help with your problem as it's specific to the tools you're using. Just try to update to the latest VSC and plugin versions. Try to freshly install a portable one and see if this improves the situation